# excel: как внутри пользовательской функции определить из какой ячейки ее вызвали

Tags: excel, vba

есть пользовательская функция `MyFunc()`

которая вызывается в некоторых ячейках таблицы

```
=MyFunc()
```

подскажите как из функции узнать в какой ячейке ее вызвали (нужно для дальнейших операция)

**P.S.**

вообще я это делаю, чтобы вот такой треш:

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(ЕЧИСЛО($A1351);ЕЧИСЛО($C1351);ЕЧИСЛО(ДВССЫЛ(АДРЕС(ПОИСКПОЗ(ДАТА(ГОД($A1351)-1;МЕСЯЦ($A1351);ДЕНЬ($A1351));$A$1:$A$100000);3))));$C1351-ДВССЫЛ(АДРЕС(ПОИСКПОЗ(ДАТА(ГОД($A1351)-1;МЕСЯЦ($A1351);ДЕНЬ($A1351));$A$1:$A$100000);3));"")
```

завернуть в функцию и вызывать просто функцию с параметром (`-1` надо заменить на параметр `- delta`)

Это же нормальная практика - вытаскивать под функции сложные коды, которые используются во многих ячейках?

Comment: Из функции никак не узнать, ведь функция может быть прописана в нескольких ячейках. Если это нужно для определения строки/столбца, используйте тип ссылок *RC*. Вы бы лучше описали, что получаете этим монстром.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function MyFunc() As String
 Dim CurRange As String
 CurRange = CStr(ActiveCell.Column) & ", " & CStr(ActiveCell.Row)
  
  MyFunc = CurRange
  
End Function
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *arif*, а если ячейка с функцией неактивна? а если функция вписана в 15 ячеек (ведь в каждой ячейке из 15 она должна определить адрес)? :)

Comment: Согласен, для неактивной ячейки и результат не будет меняться. В таком случае остается только использовать маркеры (например по свойствам ячеек или по значениям соседних) для выяснения адреса

Comment: активная ячейка - это не то, например каждая ячейка должна вывести номер своего ряда